# Can I access external hdd remotely on Synology diskstation?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, nas, synology-diskstation

I use Synology DS120j with single hdd which I'm accesing mostly with Windows 10 PC trought shortcut folder in windows explorer.
All works flawlessly.

Now I have the situation, as I want to connect external hdd trought USB ports on Synology and I want to have the data accesible in windows explorer, to be able to copy in/out data as I've been doing with internal hdd.

Is it possible ?

I can see external hdd mounted in Synology DSM. I can copy in/out files trought DSM but that's slow and painfull process. Using windows explorer would be way better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Off course this works.

But the HDD content won't show automatically as a file-share on the Syno.
You will have to create the file-share manually.

Just login to the DSM web-interface.
Use File-Station to browse to the folder on the USB drive that you wan to share.
With that folder selected in the right-hand panel in File-Station click on the "Action" button at the top and select "Share" from the pull-down menu.
Follow the wizard en you have a new share which you can map as a network drive from your computer.

Please note: If you want to disconnect the USB drive from the Syno it is best to remove that share first! Some weird effects may happen if you don't do that. Worst case you may corrupt the content of the USB drive!

Comment: I've been following your tutorial, but I've only got the option sharing it publicly(still very useful!), but I'm still unable to see it in win explorer